# How to separate numbers and arithmetic operators from a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a string I need to read it and divide it to numbers and operations for a calculator.

For example: if the input is `"22*432+33"`

I need to console to take the string as whole and add the numbers in an array till it find operation signs and push the operation sign in another array so the output result:

```
numbers = ["22", "432", "33"];
operations = ["*", "+"];
```

The language I'm using is javascript
I know the question may be board but I'm trying to solve it for a week with no success.

One of my fails attempt:

```js
var numbers = [];
var tokens = ["+", "-", "/", "*"];
var textfield = "22*432+33";

for (var i = 0; i <= textfield.trim().length; i++) {
  if (tokens.includes(textfield[i]) == false) {
    numbers.push(textfield.split());
  }
}
console.log(textfield);
console.log(tokens);
console.log(numbers);
```

The output result:

[image]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: You can create a snippet here, never share code as image.

Comment: So what exactly *is* your question?

Comment: @Liam I want the output to be 2 arrays on include the typed number and the another one the used operations so in the example in the image the output to be numbers["2", "6"] , and operationsUsed["*"]

Comment: @Durga done thanks for clarifying

Comment: It will be easy to reproduce your issue if you create a working snippet. If you don't know how to create one: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/3082296)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split your input into digits and non digits.

```js
const input = "22*432+33";
const numbers = input.split(/\D/g);
const op = input.split(/\d/g).filter(Boolean);

console.log(numbers);
console.log(op);
```

Comment: How can we join again this final arrays in an expression?